# jQuery UI Autocomplete behaviour. How to search free text on enter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

first question (and hopefully, but doubtfully my only one)

I'm using the jQuery UI Autocomplete. Here is sample code to replicate my issue.

```
var suggestions = ["C", "Clojure", "JavaScript", "Perl", "PHP"];

$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: suggestions
});
```

When a user types 'J' they will be presented with 'Clojure' and 'JavaScript' as suggestions.

I have omitted Java from this list, if the user wants to search for Java, they type 'Java', press the enter key but the form does not submit. If you add a space the 'JavaScript' suggestion disappears and the form can be submitted by pressing the enter key.

I am creating a free search, I want users to be able to search by pressing enter even if there are suggestions available.

```
$("#autocomplete").keypress(function(event) {
  alert(event.keyCode);
  if (event.keyCode=='13') $this.closest('form').submit();
});
```

I tried the above thinking I could manually detect a submit keypress and submit the form, but the alert shows all keys are detected EXCEPT submit which seems to be suppressed by the autocomplete.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE**

I had to make a few changes, but this code works fine on my side after doing that.  First, e.keycode should be e.keyCode.  I didn't think the case mattered, but it does.  Also, make sure you are not quoting the 13 when you check for the keyCode to be the enter button. It will not work correctly if you do so.  Here's the new code:

```
var suggestions = ["C", "Clojure", "JavaScript", "Perl", "PHP"];
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: suggestions
}).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
    }
});
```

---

The keypress function should look like below, and also, you can chain the autocomplete and keypress functions to make it easier on you.  Below code should work.

```
var suggestions = ["C", "Clojure", "JavaScript", "Perl", "PHP"];
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: suggestions
}).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keycode === 13) {
        $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate you taking the trouble to response.

Comment: Oops, seems Stack Overflow has the opposite problem and enter submitted my response instead of the new line I expected! This code doesn't solve the problem, for some reason the enter key, code '13' is just not recognised with keypress. It's like its been intentionally disabled, I just can't work out how to enable it! If you create a div with id='key' and add the following within the keypress function: $('#key').text('Key: ' + e.keyCode); and type you will see what I mean! It will only receive '13' if there are no suggestions. Any ideas how to force it to submit on enter? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update... still didn't work on my end (I used Chrome, your browser might handle differently?) but I've managed to get it working here too. Looking at the autocomplete code it had a keydown bind where on enter key pressed:

if ( self.menu.element.is( ":visible" ) ) { event.preventDefault(); }

This is what stopped the form submitting on enter (the default behaviour I've been trying to restore!). With this in mind, all we need to do is replace keypress with keydown and our code works in the browsers I have tried.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, the jquery-ui autocomplete widget fires the select event when the user selects a suggestion from the list, whether the selected suggestion was clicked or the enter key was pressed.  But it did nothing if the user typed text and pressed the enter key *without* selecting an item from the list.  When that happens, I need to do a search.

It was easy to add a `keypress` event handler, but it fired whether a selection had been made or not.  So I added a variable, `didSelect`,  to maintain the selection state.

Here's the complete solution:

```
$(function() {
var didSelect = false;

$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
    source: "/my_remote_search",
    minLength: 2,
    search: function (event, ui) {
        didSelect = false;
        return true;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        if (ui.item) {
            didSelect = true;
            my_select_function(ui.item);
        }
    }
}).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        if ( ! didSelect ) {
            my_search_function( $("#search").val() );
        }
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Autocomplete supresses submit but this worked as a workaround for me:

```
jQuery.fn.go_url = function(id) {
    var url="gl10.pl?ar=2010&listi=ts&niv=stovnsnr&rl=1290693052914&stovnsnr=replaceme";
    var ok;
    if (ok=id.match(/^\d{6}$/)) {
        url=url.replace(/replaceme/g,id);
        location=url;
    }
}
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#stovnar" ).autocomplete({
        source: "autocomplete.pl?pname=stovnsnr",
        minLength: 3,
        select: function( event, ui ) { if (ui.item) { jQuery.fn.go_url(ui.item.id); } }
    });
}).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        v=jQuery("#stovnar").val();
        jQuery.fn.go_url(v)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the UI Autocomplete plugin version 1.8.5:

Look for this bit of code

"case d.ENTER:case d.NUMPAD_ENTER:a.menu.element.is(":visible")&&c.preventDefault();"

and remove or comment it out.

Essentially what was said above but from the current version of the plugin.

cheers

Pete

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did

```
<div class="ui-widget"> 
    <form action="javascript:alert('hey run some javascript code')">
        <input id="search"  />
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and was thinking of using validation to accomplish this, but in the end my solution looks a whole lot easier than other solutions on this page:

1. Make an input field to type the text in, named `#input` and a hidden input named `#hiddeninput`. Your search-backend will have to use the value for `#hiddeninput`.
2. Inside your autocomplete, set the value of #hiddeninput to request.term: (I set this inside `$.ajax({ success: })` )

> $("input#hiddeninput").val(request.term);

1. Set the autocomplete with the select:-method to fill the hidden input with the suggestion that is chosen:

> ```
> select: function( event, ui ) {
>   $("input#input").val(ui.item.label),
>   $("input#hiddeninput").val(ui.item.nr),
>   //Auto-submit upon selection
>   $(this).closest("form").submit();
> }
> ```

Now your search will be performed on what the user has typed until he selects something from the suggestions-list.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#student').autocomplete({
            source: '../ajx/student_list.php',
            minLength: 3,
            response: function( event, ui ) {
                $('#student_id').val(ui.content[0].id);
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $('#student_id').val(ui.item.id);
                $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
            }
        }).keypress(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div>
    <form action='../app/student_view.php'>
        <input name='student_id' id='student_id' type='hidden' value=''>
        <label for='student'>Student: </label>
        <input id='student' />
    </form>
</div>
```

Here I used autocomplete to search for a student.  If the user pressed ENTER, the form would submit, even if nothing was selected from the list.  The 'response' event would update the value of a hidden input field with the first item in the list.  They could also click or select from the list.